# Firebase Event listener doesn't work and I can't receive the right snapshot

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, notifications, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new here, please excuse me if I didn't manage to create a good
and well formatted question.

My problem is that I can't get a snapshot of a specific child in `Firebase`.

I need to put an event listener which will return me the value( the token of the user) when there is a change in the database:

`notifications.child("tokens").child("id_user_token").child(user)`.

I also post an image of the database tree so you can see what's in there. 
My purpose is to save the token retrieved from the Database and to create a `HashMap`(to build the notification) which will contain the token, a title and a message. As you can see from the code I pass all the parameters with the `init()` function. I try to call this function in a `ViewController.swift` like this: 
`"FirebaseMessagingService.init(user: "2", title: "Test",message: "Test")"`

As you can see from the database image there is the user with `id = 2` but when I try to print the snapshot it prints `null` and I can't understand what's wrong with the code.[Image of the Database tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTrUH.png)
  [Here is the exported JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kKWA.jpg)

```
 import Foundation
 import FirebaseMessaging
 import FirebaseDatabase

 class FirebaseMessagingService{


   var mDatabase : DatabaseReference
   var notifications = DatabaseReference()



      init(user: String,title: String, message:String){

          self.mDatabase = Database.database().reference()
          self.notifications = Database.database().reference()

          notifications = mDatabase.child("notificationRequests")
          var notification = NSMapTable<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

               notifications.child("tokens").child("id_user_token").child(user).observeSingleEven  t(of: .value, with: { snapshot in


                     var token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken! as String
                     print("\n\n\n\n\(snapshot)")

                     token = (snapshot.value as? String)!

                     notification.setValue(token, forKey: "toUser")
                     notification.setValue(title, forKey: "title")
                     notification.setValue(message, forKey: "message")


                  }){ (error) in

                     print("\n\n\n\n")
                     print(error.localizedDescription)

         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code as follows

```
import FirebaseDatabase

class FirebaseMessagingService{

    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    init(user: String, title: String, message: String) {
        self.ref = Database.database().reference()

        let notifRef = self.ref.child("notificationRequests")
        let thisUserRef = notifRef.child("tokens").child("id_user_token").child(user)
        print(thisUserRef)
        thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot)
        })
    }
}
```

It should at least, print thisUserRef which should be

```
yourDataBase/notificationRequests/tokens/id_user_token/2
```

It should also print the snapshot

```
snap( 2: cq3Xy...... )
```

Let us know what prints and if the paths are correct when it does print.

Also, in your question you stated your goal to be

> I need to put an event listener which will return me the value( the
>   token of the user) when there is a change in the database:

The code your provided won't do that as it. You're using

```
.observeSingleEvent
```

Which does just that - observes a single event, one time. It will not leave a listener on the node for future events.

If you want to observe all events then use

```
   .observe(.value... (or .childAdded etc)
```

However, I don't think you meant that you wanted to observe that specific node for changes (or maybe you did). You may have meant that when there is a change in the database elsewhere, you will then need to get the uid of that user, which the code in your question is trying to do.

Last thing:

You really shouldn't be defining this as a class. It should really be a function that is called like so within your viewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var ref: DatabaseReference!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        self.showUid(user: "2", title: "some title", message: "some message")
   }

   func showUid( user: String, title: String, message: String) {
       let notifRef = self.ref.child("notificationRequests")
       let thisUserRef = notifRef.child("tokens").child("id_user_token").child(user)
       print(thisUserRef)
       thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
           print(snapshot)
       })
   }
}
```

Comment: Thnak you for the answer. I updated the code but i still get "Snap (2) <null>"

Comment: What is the problem in implementing a class like mine and the advantage of  implementing it into a ViewController ?

Comment: @MelaDeveloper If you are getting null, then you need to take a look at your path as well as how Firebase is being initialized - it's probably not correct. I have duplicated your structure and used the code in a brand new project and it works fine.

Comment: @MelaDeveloper Generally, classes need to be instantiated and can go out of scope when a function that contains them ends. I like to use them when I will have a series of similar objects that need to be worked with - a User class is a good use of a class object. For this use case, a simple function in your viewController would do what you need as shown in my answer. You code lends itself to more of a singleton pattern than a class, but since we've moved to Swift 3 and beyond, the need for singletons is diminished.

Comment: It was just an issue like the one you explained , a tree structure issue. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @MelaDeveloper Great! If the answer helped, please accept it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Wuold be glad to do it. Just explain me how to do it